# How can I play a sound with plymouth?

Tags: boot, plymouth

I want to play a sound during boot-up and I use plymouth.
Is there a way or a specific function to do that in plymouth?

Answer (score 0):

No. The sound system is loaded after the boot screen. At the earliest you can make a sound just before the login screen

You can add a script to the system in /etc/init/ that has a

```
start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
exec /usr/bin/aplay {/dir/to/audiofile}
```

But this will only work if this is done after the audio system is loaded. That is closer to the login part of the process and not at the boot screen.

Playing a sound during login is easy: you can use "startup applications" for that.